# Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask not serving static files

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, flask

I am new to Nginx and Gunicorn....

I am trying to serve flask app on certain prefix....

ex: https://myweb.com/flask/prefix/

everything works fine except it is not loading static files......

my nginx site configuration looks like below

```
location /flask/prefix/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/flask_config/flask_socket_file.sock:/;        
    }
```

when I checked the network section by using Firefox developer tool I found that it is loading home page path `/` for static files instead of this `/flask/prefix`....

Example:

/static/image.png (i.e https://myweb.com/static/image.png)

but it suppose to be /flask/prefix/static/image.png (i.e https://myweb.com/flask/prefix/static/image.png).

However I tried to remove `:/` at the end of `proxy_pass` statement... it ended with 501 error....

Please let me know what I am doing wrong....

I followed steps to configure Flask app with Nginx from [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: The problem is in the Flask app and not Nginx. I don't know Flask, but you need to set the BaseURL or the static_url_path to point to the correct prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at last....

sharing here so that it helps someone....

In your wsgi.py file....

```
from start import app

class PrefixMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app, prefix=''):
        self.app = app
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith(self.prefix):
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'][len(self.prefix):]
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
            return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]

app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, prefix='/flask/prefix')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

with this it should work...

I referred solution from [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes)